# Zooming and Panning with Pinch and Swipe gesture in a QGraphicsView with PyQt5 on Mac and Windows

Tags: python, pyqt5, gesture

I need to implement a zooming for a `QGraphicsView` on a pinch gesture (with 2 fingers) and panning along the scene with a swipe gesture (also with 2 fingers) in PyQt5.15.7 on Windows and Mac (and optimaly working for Linux aswell). I tried to achieve this with the following code:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.zoom_in_factor = 1.25
        self.zoom = 10
        self.zoom_step = 1
        self.zoom_clamp = True
        self.zoom_range = [1, 10]
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(-5000, -5000, 10000, 10000)
        self.scene.addRect(0, 0, 100, 100, QPen(Qt.NoPen), QBrush(Qt.green))

        self.setScene(self.scene)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if event.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
            # Check if mouse wheel up or down
            if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
                zoom_factor = self.zoom_in_factor
                self.zoom += self.zoom_step
            else:
                zoom_factor = 1 / self.zoom_in_factor
                self.zoom -= self.zoom_step

            # Clamping
            clamped = False
            if self.zoom < self.zoom_range[0]:
                self.zoom = self.zoom_range[0]
                clamped = True
            if self.zoom > self.zoom_range[1]:
                self.zoom = self.zoom_range[1]
                clamped = True

            if not clamped or self.zoom_clamp is False:
                self.scale(zoom_factor, zoom_factor)

            self.scene.update()

        else:
            return super().wheelEvent(event)

app = QApplication([sys.argv])

view = View()
view.show()

app.exec()
```

This code works as I want to on my Windows laptop (Asus ROG Flow X13). When I do a swipe gesture it calls the super method and handles it accordingly and (I don't know why) on a pinch gesture PyQt thinks that I am holding control and therefore executes the zooming part of the code.
However on a MacBook (as you would expect) the super method is called always (except when I hold down cmd). Therefore the zooming does not work with a pinch gesture there but the panning works.

I've tested using`QGestures` to implement the zooming with this code:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class View(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.grabGesture(Qt.PinchGesture)
        self.grabGesture(Qt.SwipeGesture)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(-5000, -5000, 10000, 10000)
        self.scene.addRect(0, 0, 100, 100, QPen(Qt.NoPen), QBrush(Qt.green))

        self.setScene(self.scene)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Gesture:
            return self.gestureEvent(QGestureEvent(event))
        return super().event(event)

    def gestureEvent(self, event):
        print("Gesture event")

        if event.gesture(Qt.PinchGesture):
            print("Pinch gesture")
            self.pinchTriggered(QPinchGesture(event.gesture(Qt.PinchGesture)))
        if event.gesture(Qt.SwipeGesture):
            print("Swipe gesture")
            self.swipeTriggered(QSwipeGesture(event.gesture(Qt.SwipeGesture)))

        print()
        return True

    def pinchTriggered(self, gesture):
        changeFlags = gesture.changeFlags()
        
        if changeFlags & QPinchGesture.ScaleFactorChanged:
            print("Scale factor changed", gesture.scaleFactor(), gesture.totalScaleFactor(), gesture.lastScaleFactor())

    def swipeTriggered(self, gesture):
        pass

app = QApplication([sys.argv])

view = View()
view.show()

app.exec()
```

While testing with this code the following things happend on the different platforms:
On Windows no gestures are registered.
On Mac only the the pinch gesture was registered. Therefore I tried realising the zooming on Mac with a pinch gesture trying a similar approach to the official [PyQt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/qtwidgets-gestures-imagegestures-example.html#image-gestures-example). This did not seem to work because the `scaleFactor`, `totalScaleFactor` and `totalScaleFactor` of the `QPinchGesture` do not change when doing the pinch gesture. They always stays at `1.0`.

Is it possible to fix this error or is there any other approach than `QGesture`s to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve it by using `QNativeGesture` (`ZoomNativeGesture`)for MacOS and using the `wheelEvent` solution for Windows. Both using simimlar logic to realize the zooming

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to monitor the `enum QEvent::Type` via:

```py
...
    def event(self, event: QEvent):
        print(f"Handling `event` ({event.type()})")  # << Print enum QEvent::Type Value
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.Gesture:
            return self.gestureEvent(QGestureEvent(event))
        return super().event(event)
...
```

And then check which event it may be in this list - search for the number:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qevent.html

I also found out your code doesn't work for me. What works is this:

```py
...
from PyQt5.QtGui import QNativeGestureEvent
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
...
    def event(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, QNativeGestureEvent) and event.gestureType() == Qt.NativeGestureType.ZoomNativeGesture:
            return self.zoomNativeEvent(event)
        return super().event(event)

    def zoomNativeEvent(self, event: QNativeGestureEvent):
        print(f"Pinch Gesture Event: pos{event.pos().x(), event.pos().y()} value({event.value()})")
        return super().event(event)
...
```

More infos you can find here:

**Qt::ZoomNativeGesture**: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnativegestureevent.html#details

**Qt::ZoomNativeGesture Constant Value**: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#NativeGestureType-enum